# mongodb : why a dbowner is not authorized to show(list) user or role?

Tags: mongodb

I created a user with the dbowner role on both test and development database

```
[admin] >show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.apiuser",
    "user" : "apiuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "rest-api-test"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "rest-api-development"
        }
    ]
}
```

after authentication

```
$ mongo -u apiuser -p my password --port 7272 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I cannot list the users on test db

```
[test] user: apiuser>show users
2017-02-22T19:03:05.744+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized    
on test to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 } :
```

neither on development db

```
[test] user: apiuser>use development
switched to db development
[development] user: apiuser>show users
2017-02-22T19:04:08.983+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized 
on development to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 } :
```

Mongodb doc indicates that the dbowner role provides the ability to perform any administrative action on the database. It combines the privileges granted by the readwrite, dbAdmin and userAdmin roles

show users is not a privilege granted by userAdmin ? not very clear...
can someone enlighten me about it ? how should I create the 'apiuser' user and roles to perform any action on the test and development database , especially CRUD users and roles...
thanks

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention :   db version v3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

found my error ...

I am using development db , I should use rest-api-development ! too bad